# How to display on/off value for the power button in console?

Tags: javascript, html, css, console.log

I have written the code for neumorphism power button and it is working perfectly fine but I'm not able to figure out how to display the status in the console using javascript, i.e., if the power button is on or off.

HTML code:

```
    <head>
  
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
  <input type="checkbox">
</body>
```

CSS Code:

```
body{
background-color: black;
padding: 0;
margin:0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
box-shadow: -10px -10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
10px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);;
position: absolute;
transform: translate(-70%,-70%);
top: 20%;
left: 80%;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 8px solid black;
outline: none ;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]::after{
font-family:FontAwesome;
content:'\f011';
color: grey;
font-size: 70px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
box-shadow: -10px -10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
10px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
inset -10px -10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
inset 10px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ;
 }

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::after{
color: green;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `change` event listener to the power button, then check whether it is checked with the `checked` property:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log(`Power button is${this.checked ? "" : " not"} checked`);
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  box-shadow: -10px -10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 10px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  ;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-70%, -70%);
  top: 20%;
  left: 80%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 8px solid black;
  outline: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]::after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f011';
  color: grey;
  font-size: 70px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  box-shadow: -10px -10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 10px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset -10px -10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 10px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::after {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="checkbox">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of posting answer I will try to guide you:

Think how will the state change - only when your input is changing. Initially it will be off.

On document load, attach an event handler for `onchange` on the input. Display the value using : `event.target.checked` . Here event is your change event.